# Preprocess view does not work?

Tags: views

I have a very basic problem:
I installed the views module and created a view...and of course the develop module.
But why does

```
function bartik_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)
{
  dpm('hi');

}
```

Not givimg me HI in template.php ? If i write that into the bartik_process_page() it works...

Comment: Regretfully, I've had the same experience, and my research lead me to articles stating that this is not functioning in D7 and not solution is provided. However, you can still create a template file and manipulate your output from there. It's messy, but it appears to be the easiest fix.

Answer (score 0):

Add a page display with an URL for your specific view, then on that page it will work and please don't forget to clear the drupal cache.